# Página de pago personalizada woocommerce

Tags: php

Buenas tardes, necesito añadir un checkbox en la página de pago de wordpress, antes de ir a pagar según el método de pago, se necesita marcar el checkbox, el checkbox solo debe aparecer para una categoría en especial, supongamos que para la categoría "Grandes" que su id es = 12 , aparezca el check obligatorio, pero para las demás categorías no aparezca nada... me explico, si una determinada categoría de producto está en mi carro aparezca el check obligatorio, alguien sabe como hacerlo y que archivo se debe modificar de wordpress o woocommerce para ello?
se me había ocurrido hacer algo así, pero no lo consigo

```
if ( is_product_category( 'extragrandes' ) ) {
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'check_field_extragrandes');
function check_field_extragrandes( $checkout ) {  
woocommerce_form_field( 'extragrandes', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label'         => __('He leído  y Acepto <a href="http://tumundohinchable.com/ejemplo/"> ejemplo</a>'),
    'required'  => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'extragrandes' ));

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo con jquery
cuando estes en la pagina que quieres controlar, analiza con firebug donde tienes alojada la categoria que necesitas
y luego en el footer.php de tu plantilla agrega un script con $(window).load() que te cree el checkbox dentro del div donde necesites crearlo 
igualmente usa jquery para determinar si se ha marcado el check antes de hacer el submit

yo he utilizado esta tecnica para cambiar los gastos de envio segun exista o no el envio gratuito.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno pues he logrado conseguir la siguiente solución

```
//Función Para Categoria Extragrande --> id = 12 --<

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'check_product_in_cart' );
function check_product_in_cart( $checkout ) {
// Verficar que el producto exista en el carrito
global $woocommerce;

//Asignar un valor negativo por defecto

$lundi_in_cart = false;

// Inicio del bucle o ciclo for para introducir los elementos de las categorias en el carrito

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
$_product = $values['data'];
    $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

// Se ejecuta una segunda búsqueda por si a caso existen varios productos con diferentes categorias.
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
        }

if (( $_categoryid === 12 ) ) {
    //La categoría existe en el carrito
    $product_in_cart = true;
    //Coloco los check obligatorios para la categoría
    //Inicio check 1
    woocommerce_form_field( 'check_1', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
    'label'         => __('No tengo más de tres escalones que subir hasta llegar al sitio del montaje.'),

    'required'  => true,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'check_1' ));
  // Fin de check1
```